# jquery toggle "children"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't use .children() here, It won't work since they aren't technically children. With this as my html,

```
    <p class="l1">A</p>
      <p class="l2">A1</p>
      <p class="l2">A2</p>
      <p class="l2">A3</p>
      <p class="l2">A4</p>
        <p class="l3">A41</p>
      ...
```

What I'm trying to do is slideToggle all the `p.l2` elements that follow `p.l1` until it reaches another `p.l1`. Code folding of sorts, but without nested children. I can't figure out how to do this.

What I've got now doesn't work, seems to hang the browser. There doesn't seem to be a .descendents() function

```
    $('p.l1').live('click', function()
    {
      var topobj = $(this);
      var done = true;
      while(done)
      {
        if($(topobj).next().hasClass('l2'))
        {
          $(topobj).next().slideToggle(100);
          topobj = $(topobj).next();
        }
        else if($(topobj).next().hasClass('l1'))
          done = false;
      }
    });
```

This seems to fail because it's given a single element rather than a set of elements. Don't really know how to achieve this...

Comment: If you close each `<p>` like you are in your example, then the next element has a `.next()`/`.previous` relationship - they aren't hierarchical at all, so you won't get a collection by selecting one `<p>`. Two things: 1 can you provide a link to a page with what you have and a diagram or graphic for what you want to achieve and 2 consider that `<p>` may not be the right tag for the job.

Comment: Why are you not using a hierarchical structure to your HTML? If it's part of the meaning of the HTML, it belongs in the HTML.

Comment: @Rob Allen, Does a link help? http://zapdos.ath.cx/test/  I suppose I could use nested `<section>` tags, paragraph tags seemed more appropriate.

Comment: @boccochoco - Thanks for the link. `<p>` is the wrong tag semantically (and for code use). Try nested `<ul>`s it will make your jQuery and your HTML cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `nextUntil`. It'll find, from the element you've passed, the next elements until it reaches something that matches with the selector that you've passed to it.

```
$(".l1").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".l1").toggle()
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BFFWM/1/)

Please consider using nested `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Good luck!

Comment: That did it, thank you. I've thought about `<ul>` and `<li>`. Forget why I ruled them out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `nextAll`, which lets you grab all the following elements that match a selector. See http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Also, I think it's failing because your `else if` should be:

```
else if($(topobj).next().hasClass('l3'))
                                 // ^---- l3 instead of l1
```

(unless there is a typo somewhere given you said you want it to continue until finding another l1, but there isn't)

Also, see what Intelekshual posted in the comments below this about [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/). That may be what you want instead.

Comment: Actually, I think he's looking for `nextUntil`. http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) is the traversal function you need:

```
$('p.l1).nextUntil('p.l1')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious ways of achieving your aim, though it'd be far easier with descendent elements.

Option one:

```
$('p.l1').click(
    function(){
        $('p.l2').slideToggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BRx7Q/).

Option two:

```
$('p.l1').click(
    function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('p.l3').slideToggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BRx7Q/1/).

Option three:

Trying to make it a little more generic:

```
$('p[class^="l"]').click(
    function(){
        var thisLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class').replace('l',''), 10);
        var nxtLevel = (thisLevel + 1);
        $('p.l' + nxtLevel).slideToggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BRx7Q/3/).

Option four:

Slightly *more* generic:

```
$('p[class^="l"]').click(
    function(){
        var thisLevel = parseInt($(this).attr('class').replace('l',''), 10);
        var nxtLevel = (thisLevel + 1);
        var prvLevel = (thisLevel - 1);
        $('p').nextUntil('p:not("p.l' + nxtLevel + '")').slideToggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BRx7Q/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for `l3` too. Just do `!$(topobj).next().hasClass('l1')`:

http://jsfiddle.net/zeb5F/